# Como posso diminuir valores de campos HTML com jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho uma classe em `PHP` que captura a `URL` de um site externo, este site em si me retorna um `HTML` no modelo:

```
<div id="isOffered">      
    <a class="price  " href="javascript:;">
        <span class="priceText wide  UK">33/20</span>
        <span class="priceText wide  EU">2.65</span>
        <span class="priceText wide  US">+165</span>
        <span class="priceText wide  CH">2.65</span>
        <span class="priceChangeArrow" ></span>
        <input type="hidden" class="betCode" value="0]SK@95553201@362904182@NB*33~20*0*-1*0*0"/>
        <input type="hidden" class="decValue" value="2.65"/>
        <input type="hidden" class="originalBetCode" value="0]SK@95553201@362904182@NB*33~20*0*-1*0*0"/>
     </a>
   </div></div>
                  <div id="s_362904184" class="odds draw suspended">   <div id="isNotOffered" class="hide">    
    <span class="price priceReadonly"></span>
   </div>

   <div id="isOffered">   
    <a class="price  " href="javascript:;">
        <span class="priceText wide  UK">19/10</span>
        <span class="priceText wide  EU">2.90</span>
        <span class="priceText wide  US">+190</span>
        <span class="priceText wide  CH">2.90</span>
        <span class="priceChangeArrow" ></span>
        <input type="hidden" class="betCode" value="0]SK@95553201@362904184@NB*19~10*0*-1*0*0"/>
        <input type="hidden" class="decValue" value="2.90"/>
        <input type="hidden" class="originalBetCode" value="0]SK@95553201@362904184@NB*19~10*0*-1*0*0"/>
     </a>
   </div></div>
                  <div id="s_362904183" class="odds away suspended">   <div id="isNotOffered" class="hide">    
    <span class="price priceReadonly"></span>
   </div>
```

Com o `PHP`, fazendo-se uso do `DOMDocument()` e do `DomXpath()`, eu busco os valores das tags `<span>`, diminuo os valores em 20% do original, obtenho o valor do campo `input betCode`, e altero os valores entre `'~'`, pois eles são os divisores responsável pelos valores no javascript, em `PHP` um amigo aqui do fórum, a tempo atrás me ajudou a fazer em `PHP`.

Mas comecei a estudar `jQuery`, e vi que posso capturar a `URL` do site com ele, sem a necessidade do `PHP`, então fiz algo simples, peguei o endereço original do site e substitui pela `URL` do meu servidor onde está sendo diminuído os valores, fiz assim:

```
$('input[value="/services/CouponTemplate.mvc/GetCoupon"]').attr('value', function(_, href){
    return "https://enderecodomeuserver.com/parser.php?url=" + href;
});
```

e funciona perfeitamente, mas minha dúvida é: teria como eu fazer o mesmo processo de diminuição dos valores usando o `jQuery`?
Como se antes do `return`, eu fizesse as diminuições usando o browser do cliente sem que fosse preciso carga no servidor.
O `jQuery` tem algo semelhante ao `DOMdocument`?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp, "JavaScript can change all the HTML elements in the page", javascript faz o que você quiser com sua pagina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra você pegar os valores utilzando jQuery a sintaxe fica mais ou menos assim:

```
var valor1 = $("#seletorUsandoIdDoSpan").text();
var valor2 = $(".seletorUsandoClasseDoSpan").text();
// caso o valor esteja em um input voce deve usar .val() ao inves de .text();

var soma = parseFloat(valor1) + parseFloat(valor2);
```

OBS:

Você terá que começar a diferenciar as suas tags com um ID único (enumerado por exemplo: priceUK1, priceUK2) ou então classes que estejam dentro de um container com ID único.

Caso contrário será dificil você com o jQuery achar o valor que você quer pois ele se utiliza de seletores, e de alguma forma esse seletor tem que buscar apenas um elemento.

Exemplo:

```
    <div id="isOffered1">      
        <a class="price  " href="javascript:;">
            <span class="priceText wide  UK">33/20</span>
            <span class="priceText wide  EU">2.65</span>
            <span class="priceText wide  US">+165</span>
            <span class="priceText wide  CH">2.65</span>
            <span class="priceChangeArrow" ></span>
            <input type="hidden" class="betCode" value="0]SK@95553201@362904182@NB*33~20*0*-1*0*0"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="decValue" value="2.65"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="originalBetCode" value="0]SK@95553201@362904182@NB*33~20*0*-1*0*0"/>
         </a>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="s_362904184" class="odds draw suspended">   <div id="isNotOffered" class="hide">    
        <span class="price priceReadonly"></span>
    </div>

    <div id="isOffered2">   
        <a class="price  " href="javascript:;">
            <span class="priceText wide  UK">19/10</span>
            <span class="priceText wide  EU">2.90</span>
            <span class="priceText wide  US">+190</span>
            <span class="priceText wide  CH">2.90</span>
            <span class="priceChangeArrow" ></span>
            <input type="hidden" class="betCode" value="0]SK@95553201@362904184@NB*19~10*0*-1*0*0"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="decValue" value="2.90"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="originalBetCode" value="0]SK@95553201@362904184@NB*19~10*0*-1*0*0"/>
         </a>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="s_362904183" class="odds away suspended">   <div id="isNotOffered" class="hide">    
        <span class="price priceReadonly"></span>
    </div>
```

Com dois containers com id diferentes: isOffered1 e isOffered2 você já consegue diferenciar seus valores usando jQuery. Exemplo:

```
var valor1 = $("#isOffered1 .priceText.EU").text(); // output: "2.65"
var valor2 = $("#isOffered2 .priceText.EU").text(); // output: "2.90"
var soma = parseFloat(valor1) + parseFloat(valor2); // output: "5.55"
```

Comment: Eu teria que de qualquer forma alterar as `id's` das `divs` com o `PHP`, pra só então fazer a soma dar certo?

Comment: Não é necessário. Você sempre tem como pegar qualquer valor da pagina via jQuery. Mas isso te facilitaria muito para definir o seletor correto dentro de $()  e encontrar o valor que vc quer.

Comment: Se o seu html for estatico e so mudarem os valores voce não precisa mesmo de ID. Mas caso varie a quantidade de campos as vezes fica inviavel fazer sem.

Comment: Ele é dinâmico, gera automaticamente as coisas.

Comment: Nesse caso seria bom colocar uma numeracao em cada "isOffered" através do php. Vc tem esse controle?

Comment: Tenho sim, mais tarde vou colocar e te mostro pra ver se está dando certo. obrigado!